# Logging payload in LoggingInInterceptor

Tags: rest, logging, jax-rs, cxf

I am using CXF REST services to connect two applications. I am passing list of Objects to other application in POST request. I realized if list size is more than 30,000, only 29998 elements of list are received on other side. I just wanted to confirm if this is true so I started digging into CXF logging code. 
LoggingOutInterceptor class logs the payload which is limited to 102400 bytes by default, so I can override it and see the payload on sending side.

But LoggingInInterceptor does not log the payload on receiving side so I cant compare payloads to see if both are same or the received one is truncated.

Is there a better way to log data sent in request body on receiving side.
Any suggestions are welcomed !

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that check was in our code in the connector configuration before starting tomcat. HTTP has no such limit check except POST request max size limit.

```
private final Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
Connector connector = tomcat.getConnector();
connector.setMaxParameterCount(30000);
```

My post request had 3 parameters in total as shown below. Now since max parameters are 30000, only first 2 parameters and 29998 from 3rd one was transferred over the wire.

To fix this issue, I changed API to accept JSON instead of form parameters. JSON object is single parameter so max parameter count is not  violated. This is how my old and new API look

old API:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
public void create(@FormParam("id") long id, @FormParam("date") LocalDate date, @FormParam("oldPkeys") List<Long> oldPkeys, @FormParam("newPkeys") List<Long> newPkeys);
```

new One:

```
@POST
@Path("/createElements")
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
public void createElements(@QueryParam("id") long id, @QueryParam("date") LocalDate date, MyJSONObject pKeys);
```

MyJSONObject is custom object which contains oldPkeys and new Pkeys